# Pointer line trail

Tags: javascript

So I'm tyring to create a specific pointer trail effect. I'm pasting the code that I'm taking as an example below. The problem is that the trail is dotted, but I'm trying to make a line. I'm trying to recreate the trail that you can see on this site:   [1]: https://argor-heraeus.com/

Example of the code that I'm using:

```js
// dots is an array of Dot objects,
// mouse is an object used to track the X and Y position
// of the mouse, set with a mousemove event listener below
var dots = [],
  mouse = {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  };

// The Dot object used to scaffold the dots
var Dot = function() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
  this.node = (function() {
    var n = document.createElement("div");
    n.className = "trail";
    document.body.appendChild(n);
    return n;
  }());
};
// The Dot.prototype.draw() method sets the position of 
// the object's <div> node
Dot.prototype.draw = function() {
  this.node.style.left = this.x + "px";
  this.node.style.top = this.y + "px";
};

// Creates the Dot objects, populates the dots array
for (var i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
  var d = new Dot();
  dots.push(d);
}

// This is the screen redraw function
function draw() {
  // Make sure the mouse position is set everytime
  // draw() is called.
  var x = mouse.x,
    y = mouse.y;

  // This loop is where all the 90s magic happens
  dots.forEach(function(dot, index, dots) {
    var nextDot = dots[index + 1] || dots[0];

    dot.x = x;
    dot.y = y;
    dot.draw();
    x += (nextDot.x - dot.x) * .6;
    y += (nextDot.y - dot.y) * .6;

  });
}

addEventListener("mousemove", function(event) {
  //event.preventDefault();
  mouse.x = event.pageX;
  mouse.y = event.pageY;
});

// animate() calls draw() then recursively calls itself
// everytime the screen repaints via requestAnimationFrame().
function animate() {
  draw();
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

// And get it started by calling animate().
animate();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

.trail {
  /* className for the trail elements */
  position: absolute;
  height: 6px;
  width: 6px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background: gold;
}
```

I'm playing with margins (left,right) , with width, but I can't "stick them" together. Anyone got an idea how I could make a clean line?

Comment: So you pasted in code from [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/anandprabhakar0507/4fae76ce94e6cb17eb641981626ee6a6) and want us to modify it to your specific requirements?  You are more likely to receive help if you first try to solve the problem yourself.

Comment: Lowering that multiplication factor of `.6` in calculation of the x/y values would be one way to get the dots closer together. You might want to add more dots then to begin with, if the line becomes too short.

Comment: I tried to change the width which works fine if you move mouse horizontality, but if moved vertically its ugly. Im playing with the multiplication factor now, and adding more dots. I also added some box shadow for a smoother look.

Comment: The linked website uses `canvas` to achieve the effect.

Comment: I used the solution that I posted, but the problem now is that elements on the site can't be clicked. Probably because cursor is making span elements above the other elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I changed this in the given code:

```
x += (nextDot.x - dot.x) * **0.05**;
y += (nextDot.y - dot.y) * **0.05**;
```

And added more dots, 80, to be precise.

I also added a more smooth transition with this CSS rules

```
-webkit-transition:90ms;
transition:90ms;
pointer-events: none;
```